# Java RCP Toolbar

Tags: java, toolbar, rcp

I'm new to RCP. I have a Question concerning the toolbar field in a .e4mxi file.
I selected the toolbar icon. Now I am wondering how I can use / access the toolbar.

Thanks for answers in advance.

[image]

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking here. Have you read a tutorial such as [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) which covers toolbars among many other things

Comment: i provided a picture. There you can see the toolbar checkbox. my question is: how can i use the toolbar?

Comment: i read the tutorial but it doesn't tell me how to do so. It only says you can add a toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select 'Toolbar' in the part a 'Toolbar' child will be added to the Part:

[image: Toolbar]

You can then select the Toolbar item and add things like 'Handled tool item', 'Direct tool item', 'Tool control' to the bar:

[image: Tool items]

Comment: that was easy :) thanks